# getting first json object correctly

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I know this seems like a simple question, but I've been working on this for two hours now.Using an ajax request, I recieve some data into the success function:

```
success: function (data) {
  alert(data);
  console.log(data);
}
```

In the console, this is the output:

```
[  
   {  
      "field1":0,
      "field2":"yes",
      "myArray":[  
         {  
            "fieldInner1":"nice",
            "fieldInner2":105532,

         },
         {  
            "fieldInner1":"nice",
            "fieldInner2":99960,

         }]
     }
]
```

It seems to me that this is an array containing one object (which was my intent).
However, when I write

```
alert(data[0].field1);
```

instead, it says undefined. When I try to have it write `data[0]` its also undefined. Help?

Comment: I can see `alert(data)` but not `alert(data[0].field1)` where are you putting this alert

Comment: What does your `alert(data)` show? Is it the same as above or `[object Object]`?

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)?

Comment: @brk I replaced alert(data) with that line

Comment: @Phil it shows the same as console.log

Comment: Then your response is plain text, not JSON. Assuming you're using jQuery, add `dataType: 'json'` to the `$.ajax` call. Better still, if you control the server-side, make sure it sets `Content-type: application/json` in the response headers

Comment: json.parse doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @Phil, I already have that as part of the call. I do cotrol server side, but I see that when I print data it prints what I expect so I dont think thats the problem

Comment: You're going to have to show more of your code. How are you making the request? Is jQuery involved or are you using something else? Also look in your browser's _Network_ console. What response headers are returned? What **exactly** does the response body look like? Please update the code in your question to show **exactly** how you're attempting to show / alert `field1`

Comment: can you try what prasanna said in the below answer `console.log(typeof data)` that would help a lot

Comment: `JSON.parse()` will not work because trailing commas are not allowed in JSON. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Trailing_commas_in_JSON) or just google 'trailing comma json'.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the response is in string format. Use `JSON.parse(data)[0].field1`

Comment: this isnt working. VM637:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: field1 is not defined
    at Object.success (<anonymous>:21:53)
    at fire (app.js:6220)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (app.js:6350)
    at done (app.js:12257)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (app.js:12500)

Answer (score -1):

I tried this, and it seems to be working as expected.

Is this not what you're getting?

EDIT: updated code.
Also note the use of `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var data = [  
  {  
  "field1":0,
  "field2":"yes",
  "myArray":[  
     {  
     "fieldInner1":"nice",
     "fieldInner2":105532,
  
     },
     {  
     "fieldInner1":"nice",
     "fieldInner2":99960,
  
     }]
    }
  ]
   
function df1(){
  alert(data[0].field1);
}

function d0(){
  alert(JSON.stringify(data[0]));
}

function d(){
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
        <h1>Alert buttons...</h1>
        <button onclick="df1()">alert - data[0].field1</button>
        <button onclick="d0()">alert - data[0]</button>
        <button onclick="d()">alert - data</button>
  </body>
</html>
```